# Cómo puedo actualizar una aplicacion propia en android desde mi servidor?

Tags: android

necesito que mi aplicación se actualice desde mi servidor cuando le doy click al boton "actualizar" encontre lo siguiente pero da error con el "uri"

```js
Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW) .setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content:///path/to/your.apk"), "application/vnd.android.package-archive"); startActivity(promptInstall);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usar un Intent para descargar un .apk y abrirlo no es posible desde la API 24, lo que debes realizar es descargar el .apk y abrirlo de esta forma.

Define un `provider` en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`, define en `android:authorities` el paquete de tu aplicación:

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="<paquete de aplicacion>"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

crea el archivo `file_paths.xml` definiendo el nombre del .apk:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="myApplication.apk" path="" />
</paths>
```

Mediante este código puedes abrir el .apk para que sea instalado, esto mediante un `Intent`:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        saveFile.setReadable(true, false);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(saveFile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        //*Define el paquete de aplicación.
        Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),<Paquete de aplicación>, saveFile);            
        intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: muchas gracias, soy nuevo en android, donde estaría indicando la direccion del nuevo apk??? y al copiar tu código me da errores, al modificarlos como me pide android studio queda así:

Comment: Voy a agregar un ejemplo, en el código sería la variable saveFile.

Comment: muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
File saveFile = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        saveFile.setReadable(true, false);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(saveFile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        //*Define el paquete de aplicación.
        Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),"com.example.ejemplo", saveFile);
        intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```